# segmentation fault. ubuntu version dependent

Tags: segmentation-fault, ubuntu-12.04

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_CMD_ARG 10
#define MAX_CMD_GRP 10

const char *prompt = "myshell> ";
char* cmdgrps[MAX_CMD_GRP];
char* cmdvector[MAX_CMD_ARG];
char cmdline[BUFSIZ];

enum STAT{
    NONE,
    FG,
    BG,

};

int status=NONE;
int pid=0;

void sigint_handler(int sign){
    fputs("\n",stdout); 
}

void fatal(char *str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}

int makelist(char *s, const char *delimiters, char** list, int MAX_LIST)
{
    if((s == NULL) || (delimiters == NULL)) return -1;

    char *snew = s + strspn(s, delimiters); /* delimiters를 skip */
    if((list[0] = strtok(snew, delimiters)) == NULL) return 0;

    int numtokens = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        if((list[numtokens] = strtok(NULL, delimiters)) == NULL) break;
        if(numtokens == (MAX_LIST - 1)) return -1;
        numtokens++;
    }

    return numtokens;
}




void execute_cmdgrp(char *cmdgrp)
{
    int count = makelist(cmdgrp, " \t", cmdvector, MAX_CMD_ARG);

    int size = strlen(cmdvector[count-1]);
    if(size > 0 && cmdvector[count-1][size-1] == '&')
    {
        status=BG;

        cmdvector[count-1][size-1] = '\0';
        if(strlen(cmdvector[count-1]) == 0) cmdvector[count-1] = NULL;

    }else{
        status=FG;
    }

    //printf(cmdvector[0]);

    switch(pid=fork())
    {
        case -1:
            fatal("fork error");
            break;

        case 0: // child process

            execvp(cmdvector[0], cmdvector);
            fatal("exec error");
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }





}

void do_if_exit_cmd(const char* cmdgrp)
{
    char* s = strdup(cmdgrp);
    makelist(s, " \t", cmdvector, MAX_CMD_ARG);

    if(strncasecmp(cmdvector[0], "exit", 4) == 0)
    {
        free(s);
        exit(0);
    }

    free(s);
}


int do_if_cd_cmd(const char* cmdgrp)
{
    char* s = strdup(cmdgrp);
    makelist(s, " \t", cmdvector, MAX_CMD_ARG);

    if(strncmp(cmdvector[0], "cd", 2) == 0)
    {
        chdir(cmdvector[1]);
        free(s);
        return 1;
    }

    free(s);
    return 0;
}


void execute_cmdline(char* cmdline)
{
    int count = makelist(cmdline, ";", cmdgrps, MAX_CMD_GRP);

    if(count==0)
        pid=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {

        do_if_exit_cmd(cmdgrps[i]);

        if(do_if_cd_cmd(cmdgrps[i])) continue;

        execute_cmdgrp(cmdgrps[i]);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);


    while(1)
    {


        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        cmdline[0]=0;
        fgets(cmdline, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1] = '\0';
        execute_cmdline(cmdline);

        if(status==FG && pid){
            int wid;
            int status;
            while((wid=wait(&status))!=pid && wid!=-1);
        }
    }
}
```

above code is simple concept shell
this shell ignore SIGINT(^C) and SIGQUIT(^)
compile this with g++ {filename}

the problem is it is working well in ubuntu 14.04 64bit and 12.04 64bit
but in ubuntu 12.04 32 bit
when I press ^C, it raises segmentation fault...

if I change &status => NULL in this line 'while((wid=wait(&status))!=pid && wid!=-1);'
it works without error

what's wrong in this code?
why dose error appear in some ubuntu version while the others not ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain things you are not permitted to do in signal handlers, one of them is to call functions that are not async-signal-safe.

One of those under POSIX systems in `fputs()` so this little snippet:

```
void sigint_handler(int sign){
    fputs("\n",stdout); 
}
```

is not really a good idea.

I tend to use signal handlers only for setting variables that can be picked up and actioned by the main thread of control, things like:

```
int finished = 0;
void sigint_handler(int sign){
    finished = 1; 
}
```

where the main program has a loop like:

```
while (!finished)
    doSomeWork();
```